# Zend_Feed_Rss - I can echo but I can't do anything else?

Tags: php, zend-feed

I would like to retrieve some feed news from a given feed source, only if a specific tag is the case.

I'm not getting it, because $category is not a string, hence strschr will not returned. (so I believe).

```
 function ultimasNoticiasBlog()
   {
        $channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss('http:/something.com/?feed=rss2');

        $news = array();

        foreach ($channel as $item) {

            foreach ($item->category as $category)
            {
                //if any of the news has the tag "Sugestão"
                if (strchr($category,'Sugestão'))
                {
                    $news['find'] = "I have found a feed with your tag";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Found Nothing';
                }
            }

          return $news;
      }
   }
```

However, if I do:
echo $category" I get all categories printed on the viewport.

What am I not getting here? Please advice,
MEM

UPDATE:
To put it simple:
**If I do:** 
`var_dump($category);` I get:

```
object(Zend_Feed_Element)#159 (3) {
  ["_element:protected"]=>
  object(DOMElement)#165 (0) {
  }
  ["_parentElement:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["_appended:protected"]=>
  bool(true)
}

object(Zend_Feed_Element)#156 (3) {
  ["_element:protected"]=>
  object(DOMElement)#166 (0) {
  }
  ["_parentElement:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["_appended:protected"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

**If I do:**
echo $category;

I get on the view port:
SugestaoAnotherTag1AnotherTag2 ...

I'm not understanding why and, more important, I'm not seeing how can I then see if "Sugestao is the case or not". :s

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [this page of the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html)

```
foreach ($channel as $item) {
    echo $item->title() . "\n";
}
```

In your case, this should work (can't try right now, tell me if it doesn't work, I'll come back to you later):

```
foreach ($channel as $item) {
  //if any of the news has the tag "Sugestão"
  if (strchr($item->category(),'Sugestão')){
     return "I have found a feed with your tag";
  }else {
     return 'Found Nothing';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it to string: `(string)$category`.